# SQL, use the result of main query into a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a column into my view. This column uses the previous result to calculate the new value.

However, it seems that it is not possible to use the result of the main query into the subquery.

To simplify the problem, it would give :

```
   SELECT DISTINCT Operation, Invoice, Corrective, 
   TestNumber = ( SELECT DISTINCT Operation, Invoice 
                   FROM Tab1
                   WHERE Operation = Tab1.Corrective)
   FROM Tab1
```

However, it does not work.

[image]

If I wrote the following, it works:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Operation, Invoice, Corrective, 
    TestNumber = ( SELECT DISTINCT Operation, Invoice 
                   FROM Tab1
                   WHERE Operation = 20483)
    FROM Tab1
```

[image]

It seems that SQL tries to extract all number where we have the condition Operation = Corrective. WhereAs what I actually want is to take the previous Tab corrective result and inject it into my subquery. How should I do?

This is the real code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Operation.Id AS OperationID, 
                dbo.Invoice.Id AS maxInvoice, 
                dbo.Operation.CorectiveId as Corective,  
                (
                    SELECT Distinct dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNumber
                    FROM dbo.Invoice INNER JOIN
                    dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id =  dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT dbo.Operation.Id as OperationID, MAX(DISTINCT dbo.Invoice.Id) as MaxInvoice
                        FROM dbo.Invoice 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
                    GROUP BY dbo.Operation.Id) sub1 ON dbo.Invoice.Id = sub1.MaxInvoice 
                                                   AND dbo.Operation.Id = sub1.OperationID

                    WHERE dbo.Operation.Id = dbo.Operation.CorectiveId
                ) as testnumber 
FROM (dbo.Invoice 
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId 
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId 
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLineHistory ON dbo.InvoiceLine.Id = dbo.InvoiceLineHistory.InvoiceLineId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dbo.Operation.Id as OperationID, MAX(DISTINCT dbo.Invoice.Id) as MaxInvoice
    FROM dbo.Invoice 
    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
    GROUP BY dbo.Operation.Id) sub ON dbo.Invoice.Id = sub.MaxInvoice 
                                  AND dbo.Operation.Id = sub.OperationID 
)
ORDER BY dbo.Operation.Id
```

Comment: try using common table expressions

Comment: what kind of are common table expressions?

Comment: you basically do your query into a common table or as many as you want. and in the end you just joins instead of subqueries. this should also be much more performant because you could queire the same result with different "where" and "disticnt" clauses https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Your SQL Seems very repetitive and messy. It's going to be hell to maintain. However, I think the root of your problem is that you don't use aliases. If you are going to use the same tables in both outer query and subquery, you need to use aliases to let the database distinguish between the two.

Comment: Hi Zohar, thank you for your reply. As I am an SQL beginner, so I am not used to doing this kind of request. My main problem is as there is a lot of different tables (using Inner Join) to join different tables, I do not know how to name these tables. It seems impossible to name a whole table with several "inner join". Have you any pieces of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Operation.Id AS OperationID,
              dbo.Invoice.Id AS maxInvoice,
              dbo.Operation.CorectiveId AS Corective,
              (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNumber
                 FROM dbo.Invoice
                      INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId
                      INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Operation operation_inner ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = operation_inner.Id
                      INNER JOIN (  SELECT dbo.Operation.Id AS OperationID, MAX (DISTINCT dbo.Invoice.Id) AS MaxInvoice
                                      FROM dbo.Invoice
                                           INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId
                                           INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId
                                           INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
                                  GROUP BY dbo.Operation.Id) sub1
                          ON dbo.Invoice.Id = sub1.MaxInvoice AND dbo.Operation.Id = sub1.OperationID
                WHERE dbo.Operation.Id = operation_inner.CorectiveId)
                  AS testnumber
FROM (dbo.Invoice
      INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId
      INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId
      INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLineHistory ON dbo.InvoiceLine.Id = dbo.InvoiceLineHistory.InvoiceLineId
      INNER JOIN dbo.Operation operation_outer ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = operation_outer.Id
      INNER JOIN (  SELECT dbo.Operation.Id AS OperationID, MAX (DISTINCT dbo.Invoice.Id) AS MaxInvoice
                      FROM dbo.Invoice
                           INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceClient ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceClient.InvoiceId
                           INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLine ON dbo.Invoice.Id = dbo.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId
                           INNER JOIN dbo.Operation ON dbo.Invoice.OperationId = dbo.Operation.Id
                  GROUP BY dbo.Operation.Id) sub
          ON dbo.Invoice.Id = sub.MaxInvoice AND operation_outer.Id = sub.OperationID)
ORDER BY operation_outer.Id
```

The thing is in differentiating to what exactly dbo.Operation table is which column connected.

For example when you wrote *WHERE dbo.Operation.Id = dbo.Operation.CorectiveId* it was as columns from the same table and query has been connected together (while you, as I understood it, wanted to connect inner query to outer query at that point).

Therefor, I gave tables aliases *operation_inner* and *operation_outer*, to differentiate  to which table what column belongs.

i hope it's working as you want it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going to re-arrange my code as it is really messy. But allias is definitively a good idea.

Comment: @MiaChen yes, making your code less messy is surely a good idea :) I kept your query as you have put it here, but I would also encourage you to change it a bit (maybe using some WITH AS might show as a good idea)